# mailto not sending text from text area in chrome

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I have mailto in my HTML and it seems to be working as it launches my default mail app (Mail on Mac).  The problem is it is not sending the text from the text area.  Below is my code.

```
<form target="_top" action="mailto:briankaty1@blueyonder.co.uk" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label>name</label>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <label>Your email</label>
    <input type="email"><br>
    <label>Your message</label>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Only form controls with a `name` can be successful controls. None of yours have a name.

---

Asides

- You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.
- [`mailto:` forms are *highly* unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). Use an HTTP(S) URL and a server-side form handler instead.

Comment: Ok will try that later.

Answer (score -1):

Just mocked this up for testing because I didn't believe this was actually possible, and what do you know - it is.  Seconding @Quentin's comment that you should not do this, but I can confirm this does populate the mail body with form content (on Debian/Firefox, anyways).

```html
<form target="_top" action="mailto:{YOUR_EMAIL}" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label>name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text"><br>
    <label>Your email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email"><br>
    <label>Your message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

Comment: Cheers will have a look tomorrow.